# To prove $\int_0^1 f^2(x) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

Let $f(x)$ be continuous in $[0,1]$ and if $\int_0^1f(x)x^n = 0 \forall n = 0,1,2...$, then prove that $\int_0^1 f^2(x) = 0$.

Comment: $f^2(x)$ as in $f(f(x))$ or $[f(x)]^2$?

Comment: What have you tried?Hint: Any continuous function on $[0,1]$ can be approximated uniformly by polynomials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Step1**: Given condition implies that $\int_0^1f(x)p(x) = 0$ for any polynomial $p(x)$

**Step2:** Let $P_n(x)$ be the sequence of polynomials which converges uniformly to $f$.Recall that Uniform convergence allows you to interchange limit and integration.Therefore,

$\int_0^1 f^2(x)dx= \int_0^1 f(x)f(x)dx=  \int_0^1 f(x)(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}P_n(x))dx=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(\int_0^1 f(x)P_n(x)dx)=0$.Hence,
$$\int_0^1 f^2(x)dx=0$$

Answer (score 0):

The key idea derives from the following theorem: Any continuous function on a compact interval can be uniformly approximated by polynomials.

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of polynomials, s.t. $\|f-f_n\|_\infty \to 0$. We have $\int_0^1 ff_ndx=0$ by assumption and thus

$$\left|\int_0^1 f^2dx \right| = \left|\int_0^1 f(f-f_n)dx \right| \leq \|f\|_\infty\|f-f_n\|_\infty \to 0$$
, which is the desired result.